# Python, Streamlit: User input is repeated whenever I submit the form

Tags: python, chat, chatbot, openai-api, streamlit

I need some help with this code. The expected output of the code below is -> user : Solar Energy of “one of the specified cities”, the bot shows a form to prompt the user of the required data then the user clicks on submit after that the bot displays solar energy is “certain number”. However, when the user clicks on submit, the bot repeats the first message that is Solar Energy of “certain city”, then shows the solar energy value.

If anyone could help with this issue.

Thank you!

The code:

```
import os
import streamlit as st
from displayer import bot_template, user_template
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.schema import SystemMessage, HumanMessage, AIMessage
from ML.Ml import CityWeatherData

def init():
load_dotenv()

    # Loading OpenAI API key
    if os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") is None or os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") == "":
        print("OPENAI_API_KEY is not set yet")
        exit(1)
    else:
        print("OPENAI_API_KEY is set")

def main():
init()

    # Initialize LangChain Chat
    chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
    
    if "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = [
            SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant.")
        ]
    
    st.header("Green Optimizer ")
    
    with st.sidebar:
        # CHATTING CODE
        user_input = st.text_input("Enter your message:")
        cities = "jeddah", "skaka", "riyadh", "dammam"
    
        if user_input:
            st.session_state.messages.append(HumanMessage(content=user_input))
            with st.spinner("Thinking.."):
                if any(city in user_input.lower() for city in cities):
                    user_city = None
                    for city in cities:
                        if city in user_input.lower():
                            user_city = city
                            break
    
                    # If city name is found, proceed with solar energy analysis
                    if user_city:
                        # Display the form for user input
                        st.write(f"Welcome! Please enter the following information for {user_city.capitalize()}:")
                        with st.form(key='weather_form'):
                            ALLSKY = st.number_input("Enter ALLSKY:")
                            CLRSKY = st.number_input("Enter CLRSKY:")
                            pressure = st.number_input("Enter pressure:")
                            temperature = st.number_input("Enter temperature:")
                            moisture = st.number_input("Enter moisture:")
    
                            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')
    
                        # If the form is submitted, calculate and display the result
                        if submit_button:
                            # Create CityWeatherData instance
                            weather_data = CityWeatherData(city=user_city)
    
                            # Analyze weather for the selected city
                            solar_energy = weather_data.analyze_weather(
                                ALLSKY=ALLSKY, CLRSKY=CLRSKY, temperature=temperature, pressure=pressure, moisture=moisture
                            )
                            # Append the user and AI messages to the conversation
                            st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=f"The Solar Energy in {user_city.capitalize()} is: {solar_energy}"))
    
                           
    
                    else:
                        # If no valid city name is found, proceed with regular chat
                        response = chat(st.session_state.messages)
                        st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=response.content))
                else:
                    # If no city name is mentioned, proceed with regular chat
                    response = chat(st.session_state.messages)
                    st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=response.content))
    
    # Displaying all the messages the user had by fetching them
    messages = st.session_state.get("messages", [])
    
    # Looping through all the messages, if 1 user(odd number) display it from the human position.
    # If two users(even number) display it from the bot position.
    for i, msgs in enumerate(messages[1:]):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            st.markdown(user_template.replace("{{MSG}}", msgs.content), unsafe_allow_html=True)
        else:
            st.markdown(bot_template.replace("{{MSG}}", msgs.content), unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have access to some of your imports, but with a few changes I was able to fix your problem. Streamlit is confusing to work with at first, because of unfamiliarity with how it executes code, but the problem is mainly with how your code is rerun in its entirety when the submission button is pressed.

**Here's a breakdown of what's happening:**

- User enters city, fills out the form, and clicks `Submit`:
- The values in the form are submitted and saved to the appropriate variables.
- After handling form submission, Streamlit usually reruns the entire script from top to bottom to update the interface.
- During this rerun, **the code outside the `if submit_button:` block also executes.** This includes the part where it appends the user input to `st.session_state.messages` and checks for city names in user input.
- The condition `if submit_button:` is triggered eventually.
- Inside this block, you create a `CityWeatherData` instance and calculate `solar_energy`.
- You append the message "The Solar Energy in... is ..." to the `st.session_state.messages`.**
- The message display loop runs and the text is displayed.

Because the code outside the `if submit_button:` re-executes to update the Streamlit UI, it doubly adds the user input to the `st.session_state.messages` container.

**How to fix this:**

You need to restructure your code to avoid the message repetition. Here is one approach:

```py
import os
import streamlit as st
# ... (rest of your imports) 

def init():
    # ... (OpenAI key setup)

####### New Function ########
def set_form_flag(bool_setting):
    st.session_state['form_submitted'] = bool_setting

def main():
    # ... (init and chat setup)

    st.header("Green Optimizer ")
    
    with st.sidebar:
        # ... (chatting code)

        if user_input:
            # only add user input str to messages if the rerun is not occuring due to form submission
            if not st.session_state.form_submitted:
                st.session_state.messages.append(HumanMessage(content=user_input))

            with st.spinner("Thinking.."):

                if any(city in user_input.lower() for city in cities):
                    # ... (city identification logic) 

                    if user_city:

                        with st.form(key='weather_form'):
                            # ... (form fields)
                            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit', on_click = set_form_flag(True))

                        if submit_button:
                            # ... (create CityWeatherData, get solar_energy)

                            # Display the solar energy result
                            st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=f"The Solar Energy in {user_city.capitalize()} is: {solar_energy}"))
                            # reset form_submitted flag here
                            set_form_flag(False)

                else:  # If no city was found
                    response = chat(st.session_state.messages)
                    st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=response.content))

            else: # if no city is mentioned
                # ... (regular chat proceeds)

    # ... (message display loop)
```

**Explanation of changes:**

- **Function `set_form_flag(bool_setting)`:** We introduce a flag to track if a rerun of the code file is being performed due to form submission.
- **Using `st.form_submit_button`'s `on_click` kwarg:** `on_click` allows us to pass the `set_form_flag` function with True as the argument as a callback so that it is recorded in `st.session_state.form_submitted` when the submit button is pressed. Callbacks in streamlit always run before the rest of the code is rerun.
- **Conditional message display:** After the form is submitted, the code is rerun top to bottom, but the inclusion of the check `if not st.session_state.form_submitted:` prevents the repetition of the user input being stored in `st.session_state.messages`.
- **Solar Energy Analysis:** As the code run progresses post submission, it still enters the `if submit_button` block, so the appropriate calculations are still performed, and an AI message is added to the message history. At the end of this block, `st.session_state.form_submitted` is set back to False, so new user inputs will again be added to the message history until the submit button is pressed again.

Let me know if you have any further questions!

For clarity, to run your code and reproduce, then fix, the behavior on my end without all your imports, it looks like:

```
import os
import streamlit as st
# from displayer import bot_template, user_template
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.chat_models.openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.schema import SystemMessage, HumanMessage, AIMessage
# from ML.Ml import CityWeatherData

@st.cache_resource
def init():
    load_dotenv()

    # Loading OpenAI API key
    if os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") is None or os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") == "":
        print("OPENAI_API_KEY is not set yet")
        exit(1)
    else:
        print("OPENAI_API_KEY is set")

def set_form_flag(bool_setting):
    st.session_state['form_submitted'] = bool_setting

def main():
    init()

    # Initialize LangChain Chat
    chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
    
    if "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = [
            SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant.")
        ]

    if "form_submitted" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.form_submitted = False
    
    st.header("Green Optimizer ")
    
    with st.sidebar:
        # CHATTING CODE
        user_input = st.text_input("Enter your message:", key = 'input_text')
        cities = "jeddah", "skaka", "riyadh", "dammam"
    
        if user_input:
            if not st.session_state.form_submitted:
                st.session_state.messages.append(HumanMessage(content=user_input))
            with st.spinner("Thinking.."):
                if any(city in user_input.lower() for city in cities):
                    user_city = None
                    for city in cities:
                        if city in user_input.lower():
                            user_city = city
                            break
    
                    # If city name is found, proceed with solar energy analysis
                    if user_city:
                        # Display the form for user input
                        st.write(f"Welcome! Please enter the following information for {user_city.capitalize()}:")
                        with st.form(key='weather_form'):
                            ALLSKY = st.number_input("Enter ALLSKY:")
                            CLRSKY = st.number_input("Enter CLRSKY:")
                            pressure = st.number_input("Enter pressure:")
                            temperature = st.number_input("Enter temperature:")
                            moisture = st.number_input("Enter moisture:")
    
                            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit', on_click = set_form_flag(True))
    
                        # If the form is submitted, calculate and display the result
                        if submit_button:
                            # Create CityWeatherData instance
                            # weather_data = CityWeatherData(city=user_city)
    
                            # Analyze weather for the selected city
                            # solar_energy = weather_data.analyze_weather(
                            #     ALLSKY=ALLSKY, CLRSKY=CLRSKY, temperature=temperature, pressure=pressure, moisture=moisture
                            # )
                            solar_energy = 500
                            # Append the user and AI messages to the conversation
                            st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=f"The Solar Energy in {user_city.capitalize()} is: {solar_energy}"))
                            set_form_flag(False)                                                      
    
                    else:
                        # If no valid city name is found, proceed with regular chat
                        response = chat(st.session_state.messages)
                        st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=response.content))
                else:
                    # If no city name is mentioned, proceed with regular chat
                    response = chat(st.session_state.messages)
                    st.session_state.messages.append(AIMessage(content=response.content))
    
    # Displaying all the messages the user had by fetching them
    messages = st.session_state.get("messages", [])
    
    # Looping through all the messages, if 1 user(odd number) display it from the human position.
    # If two users(even number) display it from the bot position.
    for i, msgs in enumerate(messages[1:]):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            st.markdown( msgs.content, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        else:
            st.markdown(msgs.content, unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One final note / change.. I also added `@st.cache_resource` above the `init()` definition. This will prevent this function from running any other time than the first time `main()` is run.You can look at the streamlit docs to see more about caching data or resources.